# Getting post array data from codeigniter checkbox array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, post, checkbox

I have an list of checkboxes within a view which are generated through a foreach loop `form_checkbox('jobseeker[]', $application['jobseeker_profile_id']);`.

At the moment I have 2 rows generated from this but there seems to be a problem when hitting the submit button. When I hit the submit button after checking the 1st checkbox generated I get an error `Undefined variable: candidates` and foreach errors, When I hit the submit button after checking both checkbox's generated I get an error `Undefined variable: candidates` but when I only check the second checkbox I get no errors and it does what it should do on the next page.

I'm asking is what is wrong with my current code which would prevent multiple checkboxes to be clicked without error?

CHECKBOX VIEW

```
foreach($applications as $application){

$value = $application['points_value'] * $this->session->userdata('price');

echo "<tr class=\"row\" style=\"background: green\">";  
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo $application['name'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
foreach($skills as $myskills){
    echo $myskills[$i]['name'];     
}
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
foreach($qualifications as $myqualifications){
    echo $myqualifications[$i]['name'];
}
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
foreach($workhistory as $myhistory){
    echo $myhistory[$i]['role'];
}
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo form_open('resume');
echo form_hidden('jobseeker_id', $application['jobseeker_profile_id']);
echo form_submit('submit'.'" class="submitButton"', 'View CV'); 
echo form_close();
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo $value;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"column\">";
echo form_open('applications/interview');
echo form_checkbox('jobseeker[]', $application['jobseeker_profile_id']);
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}

echo form_submit('Submit'.'" class="submitButton"', 'Continue');
echo form_close();
```

CONTROLLER

```
    $this->load->view('header');

    $applicants = $this->input->post('jobseeker');

    $data = array();

    foreach($applicants as $applicant => $id){

        $data['candidate'] = $this->db->get_where('jobseeker_profiles', array('id' => $id ))->row_array(); 
        $data['candidates'][] = $data['candidate'];

    }

    $this->load->view('payment', $data);
```

OUTPUT VIEW

```
foreach($candidates as $candidate){
$value = $candidate['total_points_value'] * $this->session->userdata('price'); 

echo $candidate['name']." - "."&pound;".number_format($value, 2, '.', '');

$total += $value;
}
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Total Payment: &pound;".number_format($total, 2, '.', '');

echo form_open('applications/payment');
echo form_hidden('amount'.'" value="'.$total.'');
echo form_submit('submit'.'" class="submitButton"', 'Make Payment');
echo form_close();
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have to `echo` your table so hard?

Comment: @Jari entirely irrelative to the question I asked really but if you could provide some solution to the problem in question then please be my guest

Comment: I posted it into comments, not to answers, right?

Comment: I suppose but if you can help that would be great.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I have 2 forms but unsure how I would implement two forms as I need that functionality

Comment: You can not send two forms at once in HTML.